# CakePHP Switching default database after login

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am currently working on a project to provide users an own database after logging in. The project contains a login form with users stored in our own database (default). Once logged in the default database needs to change to the one the user provided while signing up. I am quite far to getting it working but I got stuck on selecting the right table. I have over 10000 Find functions so setting $this-Model->setDataSource("otherdatabase"); for each function is not really an option. The problem I am facing is that queries do not update.

The code I am using is as following in AppController.php:

```
public function beforeFilter(){     

    if($this->Auth->loggedIn()){        
                ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')->disconnect();
                $newconnnection = array(
                                'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
                                'persistent' => false,
                                'host' => '123456789',
                                'login' => 'user1',
                                'password' => 'password1',
                                'database' => 'newdatabase',
                                'prefix' => '',
                                'encoding' => 'UTF8',
                                'port' => '',
                );
                ConnectionManager::drop('default');
                ConnectionManager::create('default', $newconnnection );
                ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')->reconnect();                   

                $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
                debug($db->config['host']); // this displays newdatabase
            }

        }

    }
```

The query output is as following and does not change to the right database I set. In the query the FROM contains the old database. Even though debugging the database variable displays the new one.

```
SELECT `user`.`id`,`user`.`name`,`user`.`password` FROM `olddatabase`.`users`
```

Anyone knows a solution for this problem or any other way to check if the user is logged in and change the database globally?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't set the data source in the models declaratively to something other than `default` (rather than changing it for each query), and then modify the connection details for that other data source dynamically on log in?

Comment: I could set public $useDbConfig = 'client' in each model after the login but paginators ignore this. Also the code in the example works when the database name is the same as the old one since the query is correct like that. But the requirement is to make this variable.

Comment: So you're saying the models need to be able to query both the common/default database and the client-specific one? If the data for certain models always comes from the client database, why not just set `$useDbConfig` inside the model code and not set it at runtime at all?